# Visual Studio 2019 Community loading project with Error

Tags: visual-studio-2019

SDK REsolver manifest file is invalid. This may indicate a corrupt or invalid installation of MSBuild. Manifest file path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\SdkResolvers\Microsoft.Build.NuGetSdkResolver\Microsoft.Build.NuGetSdkResolver.xml'. Message: There was an error deserializing the object of type Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.SdkResolution.SdkResolverManifest. The data at tje root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1. C:\Code\todo-api-master\todo-api.csproj[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZU3W.png)

Comment: What troubleshooting did you perform?

Comment: This is new installation and had done many times. But this time the installation was done in two steps. So just uninstalled the visual studio and will try reinstalling.